# Django/MySQL time datatype

Tags: python, mysql, django

I´m using Django to import from an existing mysql database thats already created and is used by somebody else. Im using:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

And the class from my model in question is the following:

```
class Funciones(models.Model):
    idfuncion = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    idpelicula = models.ForeignKey(Peliculas, db_column='idpelicula')
    idcine = models.ForeignKey(Cines, db_column='idcine')
    hora = models.TextField() # This field type is a guess.
    tipo_3d = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'3d', blank=True) # Field renamed
    xd = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    gtmax = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    vip = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    idioma = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    idciudad = models.ForeignKey(Ciudades, db_column='idciudad')
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'funciones'
```

Now this attribute:
   ***hora = models.TextField() # This field type is a guess***

corresponds to a *time* dataType in MYSQL.
Now, since I cant change the dataType in MYSQL because somebody else has already created a number of queries to the database from another app, I would like to know what would be the appropriate corresponding django datatype that I should use in my django model.
I was thinking *DateTimeField* but then I should have to somehow truncate the date part before writing to the database.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**Edit:**

As pointed out by Pedro:

Django actually has a TimeField, why not use that? – Pedro Romano

Comment: Django actually has a [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield), why not use that?

Comment: Oops, my bad, seems like I missed the *TimeField*. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Timedelta object to represent "time elapsed" using this https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1060/